# Linkedin Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates OR

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, yii2, httpclient, linkedin-api

I'm trying to get access token from Linkedin calling url https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken as described at https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2 using php + curl

But I get an error `Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates`
If I try to set curl option CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to false - I get anotger error `403 Forbidden`.

```
    $client = new \yii\httpclient\Client([
        'transport' => 'yii\httpclient\CurlTransport',
    ]);
    $response = $client->createRequest()
        ->setMethod('post')
        ->setUrl('https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken')
        ->addHeaders(['content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'])
        ->setData([
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'code' => $_GET['code'],
            'redirect_uri' => 'http://test-network.tk/user/settings/test',
            'client_id' => 'MY_CLIENT_ID',
            'client_secret' => 'MY_CLIENT_SECRET',
        ])
        ->setOptions([
            'sslVerifyPeer' => false,
        ])
        ->send();
```

Please help me

PS: If I try to call same url using GET via browser or linux command line - all is ok, and I get a access token!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved. Just I used a russian hosting provider, but in Russia Linkedin are blocked - https://blocklist.rkn.gov.ru/#anchor
But my local computer located at Ukraine, so my request was succesfull from browser and terminal.